# How to mirror production server using docker-compose for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose` file for running a Wordpress website.

```
version: "3.9"
    
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin123
    networks:
      - wpsite
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
    volumes:
      - "../../blogs:/var/www/html"
      - "../../blogs/plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins"
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Here I am using the official `wordpress:latest` image, but my production server has a different configuration. I would like to use the same PHP version and other configurations. How can I do it ?

Comment: create a Dockerfile for this and in the Dockerfile you start it like this : `FROM wordpress:latest` and do all the actions you want inside

Comment: It will be helpful if you can show an example.

Comment: This is some Dockerfile i have : `FROM python:3-stretch
ADD  app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated install ansible net-tools
RUN ansible-galaxy install PaloAltoNetworks.paloaltonetworks
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements_server.txt
CMD ["python", "server.py"]
`